# How to use S3 SSE C (Server Side Encryption with Client Provided Keys) with Ruby

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, encryption, aes

I'm trying to upload a file to S3 and have it encrypted using the [SSE-C encryption options](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ServerSideEncryptionCustomerKeys.html). I can upload without the SSE-C options, but when I supply the sse_customer_key options I'm getting the following error:

> ArgumentError: header x-amz-server-side-encryption-customer-key has field value "QkExM0JGRTNDMUUyRDRCQzA5NjAwNEQ2MjRBNkExMDYwQzBGQjcxODJDMjM0\nnMUE2MTNENDRCOTcxRjA2Qzk1Mg=", this cannot include CR/LF

I'm not sure if the problem is with the key I'm generating or with the encoding. I've played around with different options here, but the AWS documentation is not very clear. In the general SSE-C documentation it says you need to supply a **x-amz-server-side​-encryption​-customer-key** header, which is described as this:

> Use this header to provide the 256-bit, base64-encoded encryption key
>   for Amazon S3 to use to encrypt or decrypt your data.

However, if I look at the Ruby SDK documentation for [uploading a file](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/Aws/S3/Object.html#upload_file-instance_method) the 3 options have a slightly different description

- :sse_customer_algorithm (String) — Specifies the algorithm to use to when encrypting the object (e.g.,
- :sse_customer_key (String) — Specifies the customer-provided encryption key for Amazon S3 to use in
- :sse_customer_key_md5 (String) — Specifies the 128-bit MD5 digest of the encryption key according to RFC

(I didn't copy that wrong, the AWS documentation is literally half-written like that)

So the SDK documentation makes it seem like you supply the raw sse_customer_key and that it would base64-encode it on your behalf (which makes sense to me).

So right now I'm building the options like this:

```
  sse_customer_algorithm: :AES256,
  sse_customer_key: sse_customer_key,
  sse_customer_key_md5: Digest::MD5.hexdigest(sse_customer_key)
```

I previously tried doing `Base64.encode64(sse_customer_key)` but that gave me a different error:

> Aws::S3::Errors::InvalidArgument: The secret key was invalid for the
>   specified algorithm

I'm not sure if I'm generating the key incorrectly or if I'm supplying the key incorrectly (or if it's a different problem altogether).

This is how I'm generating the key:

```
require "openssl"
OpenSSL::Cipher.new("AES-256-CBC").random_key
```

Comment: `Base64.strict_encode64(key)` maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, did you notice that your key contains '\n'? That's most probably why you get the CR/LF error:
`QkExM0JGRTNDMUUyRDRCQzA5NjAwNEQ2MjRBNkExMDYwQzBGQjcxODJDMjM0(\n)nMUE2MTNENDRCOTcxRjA2Qzk1Mg=`

As mentioned by the colleague in the comments, [strict_encode64](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.1/libdoc/base64/rdoc/Base64.html) is an option, as it complies to RFC 2045.

By the way, I got this insight from here: https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/14664

Hope it helps! :)

Comment: I'm not 100% confident this is the answer (yet). If I do I'll update here!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, please make sure that you are using the latest version of the SDK (2.2.2.2) from [here](https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-net/)

So, As I understand while we generate the presigned URL, we have to specify the SSECustomerMethod and when consuming the URL, the "x-amz-server-side-encryption-customer-key" header is set with the customer key, you also need to set the "x-amz-server-side-encryption-customer-algorithm" header.

```
var getPresignedUrlRequest = new GetPreSignedUrlRequest
{
    BucketName = bucketName,
    Key = "EncryptedObject",
    SSECustomerMethod= SSECustomerMethod.AES256,
    Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(5)
};
var url = AWSClients.S3.GetPreSignedURL(getPresignedUrlRequest);
var webRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
webRequest.Headers.Add("x-amz-server-side-encryption-customer-algorithm", "AES256");
webRequest.Headers.Add("x-amz-server-side-encryption-customer-key", base64Key);

using (var response = webRequest.GetResponse())
using (var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
{
    var contents = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Comment: This is not Ruby